# Как получить несколько моделей в Laravel c пагинацией?

Tags: laravel

Подскажите как получить несколько моделей в одной LengthAwarePaginator

Коллекцию получить выходит, делаю так:

```
$clinic =  Actions_clinic::select('*')->get();
    if($clinic){
        $clinic->load(
            'actions_clinic',
            'actions_clinic.districts',
            'actions_clinic.metros'
        );
    }
    $analyze =  Actions_analyze::select('*')->get();
    $collection  = new Collection;
    $actions = $collection->merge($clinic)->merge($analyze);
    return $actions;
```

Как мне добавить пагинацию суда?

Answer (score 0):

```
$clinic =  Actions_clinic::select('*')->paginate(100);
```

Разве не так?

Comment: Если одна модель то так, но если объединяешь потом то не работает((